# I am not able to create a vector of Poco::Threads

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

I am creating a vector of Poco Threads like this:

```
using Poco::Thread;
std::vector<Thread> threads;
Thread pt;
threads.push_back(pt);
```

and I get the following error:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2248: 'Poco::Thread::Thread' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Poco::Thread'

What is the reason and which container should I use to store threads?

Comment: Is that the *complete* error message? At what line in *your* code do you get the error?

Comment: I am getting error at 2nd line.

Comment: What, at the line `std::vector<Thread> threads;`? Please *edit your question* to include a comment on the line you get the error. And of course copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error message into the question as well.

Comment: I think Poco is the namespace and Thread is a class inside it. So perhaps you intended to do using Poco; instead of using Poco::Thread;

Comment: That is not yhe complete error message.  Yhe compiler is emitting notes, warnings, or other lines or errors.  You are omitting them.  Do not omit diagnostics that the compiler is generating.  The line *right next to the one you shared* describes the problem, most likely.

Comment: @user3286661 - No the OP meant to use a using declaration to pull in just *one identifier* instead of a using directive that pulls in the entire namespace. And it's not the source of their problem. at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Poco::Thread`'s can only be moved, *not* copied, and so rely on having a move constructor/move assignment operator. You are using an ancient version of Visual Studio which doesn't support proper move semantics.

You need to upgrade your visual studio to something which isn't over 5 years old

Answer (score 0):

```
func(){ do something }

std::thread th1(func);
std::thread th2(func);
```

// Move thread objects to vector

```
 vecOfThreads.push_back(std::move(th1));
    vecOfThreads.push_back(std::move(th2));
```

// Add a Thread object to vector

```
vecOfThreads.push_back(std::thread(func));
```